# Blazor top Nav row -> how to prevent other elements hover over it?

Tags: html, css, blazor-server-side

I created a new Blazor server-side project.
So default clean layout.
I wanted to make a `card/column` layout on my page.
But when the page is getting big, I can scroll the page, so when I scroll down, the "card" will hover ABOVE the top row menu bar. That is the same issue when using "div class col"for example.
[Example to make it more clear](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KrmHs.png)

It does not happen when I use `img` tag, so if I would make 10 big images between the `img` tag to force the website to have a scrollbar, the images are behind the top row menu.

But just between a "div" with no col, that is still fine, but is not, this will hover OVER the top row.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-1">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="Images/63.gif" style="max-width:100%;">
     </div>
</div>
```

So how can I make sure that the top row bar is ALWAYS on top and that everything will always be behind it like when using a simple `<img>` tag?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Blazor the default template has the top row with a CSS class of `top-row`, so hop into your site.css file and add at the bottom:

```
.top-row {
z-index: 100;
}
```

This should bring the top row forward toward the viewer like you are asking. You might need to play with that z-index value to get it where you want it, but this should help.